# Why doesn't my program execute (work)?

Tags: keil, stm32f0, cortex-m0, j-link, stm32cubemx

I have bought this board for working on Cortex-M0 series microcontrollers. its MCU is STM32F030F4P6. this is the board:

[image: board]

[image: pcb]

and its schematic:

[image: schematic]

I used STM32CubeMX for configure the MCU and then used MDK-5 (keil uvision) for writing a Blink program. the program is this:

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * File Name          : main.c
  * Date               : 23/06/2014 17:53:47
  * Description        : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  *
  * COPYRIGHT(c) 2014 STMicroelectronics
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
  * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
  *   1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  *   2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *      this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *      and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  *   3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of its contributors
  *      may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software
  *      without specific prior written permission.
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
  * AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
  * IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
  * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
  * FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
  * DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
  * SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
  * CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
  * OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
  * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f0xx_hal.h"

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);

void  Delay (uint32_t nCount)
{
  for(; nCount != 0; nCount--);
}

int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* System interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  /* Infinite loop */
  while (1)
  {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA , GPIO_PIN_0);
        Delay(0xfffff);
        Delay(0xfffff);
        Delay(0x5ffff); 
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA , GPIO_PIN_0);
        Delay(0xfffff);
        Delay(0xfffff);
        Delay(0x5ffff); 

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL12;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PREDIV = RCC_PREDIV_DIV1;
  HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1);

  __SYSCFG_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __GPIOF_CLK_ENABLE();
  __GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA1 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_1;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
/* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif

/**
  * @}
  */ 

/**
  * @}
*/ 

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

I compiled it and the keil made the HEX file very well. I have to connect the board to J-Link like this picture:

[image: connect]

ok, allright, I connected it right like it. look:

[image: J-Link1]

[image: J-Link2]

I download the program. so far all things are fine but it's not work!

[image: circuit]

In your opinion, where am I wrong?

Comment: The listing provided appears to toggle Port A bit 0. The LED on the schematic is on Port B bit 1. The LED on your breadboard appears to be on pin A1 not A0. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, it should toggle port A bit 0. I corrected it. Now, it's on port A bit 0. still, it's not work.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Also I think the schematic of board is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to waltx and special thanks to him and @BrianDrummond . I found the problem. add to the answer of both guys, the big problem was 'delay()' function. it made a big delay for Blink. I replaced one 'Delay(0x29020c0)' after toggle function and now it's works. Thanks again, guys.

Answer (score 2):

In the function  "void MX_GPIO_Init(void)" pin 1 is being initialized.

In the loop, pin 0 is being toggled.